# There is a Design Pattern related to this solution?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

There is a solution that I use frequently, I would like to know if there is an design pattern that is related to this solution:

I want modify properties of an object, and i would like to separate each responsability in different classes and also be able to add/remove easier those responsabilities.

There is Pattern to name this solution? It is a good solution or there is another pattern this fix it better?

Thank you!

```
class Choice 
{
    private $isSelected;

    private $isRight; 
}

class ChoiceModifierInterface
{
    public function modify();
}

class Selector
{
    public function modify(Choice $choice)
    {
        //check if the user select the question 
        $choice->isSelected(true);
    }
}

class Corrector
{
public function modify(Choice $choice)
    {
        //check if the question is right
        $choice->isRight(true);
    }
}


class ChoiceModifier
{
    public function add(ModifierInterface $modifier)
    {
        //add classes
    }

    public function modify(Choice $choice)
    {
        foreach ($this->modifiers as $modifier)
        {
            $modifier->modify($choice);
        }
    }
}

class Client
{
    public function main()
    {
        $choiceModifier = new ChoiceModifier();
        $choiceModifier->add(//add all modifiers);

        //run all modifiers
        $choiceModifier->modify($choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer but it looks to be [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

The way I usually use Composite patter is for example with logging. When I want to log to multiple places at the same time (like file, some cloud error tracking system, debug window and maybe more) I create single logger abstraction then I implement this abstraction in all my loggers and create Composite logger. Composite logger logger also implements logger interface and it contains collection of all other loggers. The only responsibility of Composite logger is to delegate the invocation to all loggers it contains. This way you can log to multiple places with just one invocation in the client code.

I never used composite patter to modify objects state but I can imagine that in certain scenarios it might be a good solution.